# KeyError with a a valid key

Tags: python, dictionary

```
    def askme(answers):
            question = raw_input("Do you want to see my name, age or favorite fruit?\n")
            if not question in answers:
                    print "I have no answer for that, ask something else"
                    askme(answers)
            answer_to_question = answers[question]
            return answer_to_question

    answers = {"name":"John", "age":18, "fruit":"apple"}

    while True:
            answer_to_question = askme(answers)
            print "Answer is %s" % answer_to_question
```

How I want it to run:
If the input is not in dictionary, ask for new input
If the input is in dictionary, use input as a key

What's wrong:
After I pass in a value that is not in key, it asks me for new input. If I pass in a value that is in a key, I get a KeyError.

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: you should raise an error when question is not found instead of calling `askme` again. Then you catch the error outside the function instead of printing the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you are recursing. When an invalid question is asked, the program correctly notices and recurses, but after an answer is found it starts back where it left off.

I think the best fix is to change the top part of the function to avoid the recursion:

```
question = raw_input("Do you want to see my name, age or favorite fruit?\n")
while not question in answers:
    print "I have no answer for that, ask something else"
    question = raw_input("Please type 'name', 'age' or 'fruit'.\n")
```

An alternative fix would be to keep the recursive format, but prevent the program from resuming where it left off if the question asked was invalid. In this case, you'll just want to replace the recursive call with:

```
return askme(answers)
```

Comment: Yes, when you call a function, the program puts its current code on hold and runs the function's code. When the function ends, control returns to the location of the function call and the original code resumes. Recursion doesn't change this.